# Try catch (IOException g) Error

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

I get the error `exception java.io.IOException is never thrown in body of corresponding try statement` if I try to catch an `IOException`. But if I use `Exception` instead, the error is gone.
Can someone describe why this happens?

```
public class CmndLine {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int i, j = 0;
        long m, l;
        boolean b1 = false;
        String str = "";
        String [] s;

        for (i = 0; i < args.length; i++)
            str += args[i];

        File file = new File(str);

        try {
            b1 = file.exists();
            System.out.println(b1);

            if (b1 == true) {
                m = file.lastModified();
                l = file.length();
                s = file.list();
                java.util.Date d = new java.util.Date(m);
                System.out.println("Name : " + file.getName());
                System.out.println("Parent : " + file.getParent());
                System.out.println("Path : " + file.getPath());
                System.out.println("Date and Time of Modification : " + d);
                System.out.println("Size : " + l + " Bytes");
                boolean c = file.isDirectory();

                if (c == true) {
                    System.out.println("");
                    for (String t : s)       
                        System.out.println(t);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (IOException g) {
            g.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you give a full traceback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the methods you are using in your `try` block declare that they throw checked exceptions of type `IOException`, therefore you cannot `catch` it.

Since `Exception` encompasses both checked and unchecked exceptions, it doesn't give you the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is no command in your `try` block that could throw an `IOException`. Therefore you will never catch one and your IDE/Compiler is telling you that.

If you write `catch(Exception e)` instead, you'll catch any possible `Exception`, like the `SecurityException` that methods like `File.exists()`, `File.lastModified()` and `File.length()` can throw.

So, try to use `catch(SecurityException e)` instead and add additional `catch` blocks for any specific `Exception` type you want to catch.